# How can I install Sharepoint 2010 and use SQL on a remote server?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm installing Sharepoint 2010 for the first time, I want to install it on server A and use a SQL 2008 R2 installation on server B, when I run the Sharepoint installer it automatically installs SQL express locally. How can I change this?

Many thanks
Steven

UPDATE: Just found it, you have to say you want a Farm installation even though I only want the one server.

Answer (score 1):

What options are you selecting on the install wizard? You should be using the farm option to use a remote SQL Server.